# Swift CoreData Edit/Update entity, when there is only 1 instance of it

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

This question seems to have been asked a lot already. But I havn't been able to find a swift solution.

I have an entity named "User" which there should only ever be one of. So after it has been created for the first time. I need to edit/update it's values rather than creating more.

I did find a video on it on youtube. Which is the attempt provided below. However it doesn't work.

This is my code in the viewController Class before `viewDidLoad()`

```
// Core data setup
let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
var newUser : User? = nil
var results = NSArray()

var hasAccount = Bool()
```

Here's my code in `viewDidLoad()`

println(newUser)

```
    // Core data fetching
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
    if results.count > 0 {
        hasAccount = true
        var res = results[0] as NSManagedObject
        println(res.valueForKeyPath("email")!)
    }
    else {
        println("No Account")
    }
```

I use the above code, to figure out if there is already something in the User entity, (then setting `hasAccount` to "true"). However, if you happen to know a better way to do this. it would be very appreciated!

I printed out "newUser" in hopes that I could make it print the User object. So I could just check `if newUser != nil { do this }` However all my attempts of getting "User" outside of the above workaround has failed.

Now the code that I havn't been able to get to work in any way is this:

```
let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: context)

if hasAccount == false {
                    println("Creating a new User Object")
                    let newUser = User(entity: ent!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
                    newUser.firstName = firstNameTextField.text
                    newUser.lastName = lastNameTextField.text
                    newUser.email = emailTextField.text
                    newUser.password = passwordTextField.text
                    newUser.accountType = 0
                    context.save(nil)
                } else {
                    println("Updating existing User Object")
                    newUser?.firstName = firstNameTextField.text
                    newUser?.lastName = lastNameTextField.text
                    newUser?.email = emailTextField.text
                    newUser?.password = passwordTextField.text
                    newUser?.accountType = 0
                    context.save(nil)
                }
                println(newUser)
```

The part that's creating a new User object. Should work. (However untested since I moved it into an if statement)

But the part that's supposed to update the entity, doesn't work. I know it runs due to the `println`.

But it doesn't change the User Entity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Too late for me to write an answer, but here is a hint: `let newUser = User(...)` creates a local variable whose scope is limited to the if-block, and which is completely unrelated to the `var newUser : User?` property. – It might be sufficient to remove the word "let" in that line ...

Comment: If there should only ever be one `User`, what are you using Core Data for?

Comment: @TomHarrington I was under the impression that CoreData was used for anything that saves data on the devices' memory. Is there an easier way to  create/read/update/delete data locally?

Comment: There are lots of ways to save data including, but not limited to, `NSKeyedArchiver`, reading/writing arrays and dictionaries via `writeToFile:atomically:` and others. You can make up your own file formats and read/write whatever bits you want with `NSFileHandle`. There are other options (e.g. Unix style file access) as well.

Comment: @TomHarrington That was perfect. I ended up using a plist file to save my dictionary. Much much easier than coreData, in this case. Thank you! You can go ahead and provide it as an answer. Although, I'll probably need to change the title to something else. Since this isn't an answer to the original question, but a better way to do it in this particular case. Not quite sure what I can change it to, so it's not misleading though :/

Comment: I strongly disagree with the advice supplied here. @TomHarrington we are here to guide and help people write better code. It's a complete copout to say that if you only need one entity then don't use core data. What happens when he decides to support multiple accounts etc. Core data is a perfectly suitable solution to store a single entity.

Comment: @DanielGalasko then write your own answer to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me start by saying that Core Data is an incredibly powerful framework for persisting and maintaining object graphs. That being said it does, unfortunately, require a large amount of effort just to get started. For this particular reason I typically recommend to beginners looking at [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord). It's a delightful library that removes almost all of the boiler plate code required setting up the stack and maintaining and creating contexts.

Mattt Thompson (I do miss his writing) wrote an insightful [post](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/) regarding when you should consider CoreData versus NSKeyedArchiver etc. Always handy to keep for reference.

I broke my solution up into two parts, in the first part I reviewed your original question just to give you some basic pointers. The last part I deal with MagicalRecord as I really feel that it might be better suited for you given its lighter learning curve. We are here to ship apps after all, learn Core Data as you get deeper into iOS.

### Question Review

Before I dive into things I want to explore some of the mistakes we can rectify with your solution so you can understand why its not working.

```
// Core data setup
let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
```

I know Apple throw the context into the AppDelegate but its a really messy hack and I typically find its best to have a CoreData singleton somewhere that wraps your contexts. Its nice to stay true to the singular responsibility principle, the App Delegate is responsible for handling App Events and instantiating the ViewController hierarchy. NOT for managing the core data stack.

```
var newUser : User? = nil
var results = NSArray()
```

This is swift, why not var `results:[AnyObject] = []`

```
var hasAccount = Bool()
```

you mean, `var hasAccount = false`....

But lets fast forward, you don't need to define all these variables upfront, anyone reading your code has to scan so many lines before they actually get to the root of what you are trying to achieve. Lets clean it up:

```
// Core data fetching
let userRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
userRequest.fetchLimit = 1
if let user = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)?.first as? User {
   //now we have a user
} else {
   //no user
}
```

One of the big gotchas that newcomers don't realize is that an `NSManagedObjectContext` save operation only saves one level up. If that context descends directly from the persistent store then your changes will be saved to disk but if it isn't, that save needs to recursively call save on that contexts parent etc. Here's the documentation:

> If a context’s parent store is a persistent store coordinator, then
>   changes are committed to the external store. If a context’s parent
>   store is another managed object context, then save: only updates
>   managed objects in that parent store. To commit changes to the
>   external store, you must save changes in the chain of contexts up to
>   and including the context whose parent is the persistent store
>   coordinator.

So if your context has a parentContext then your save operation will never be saving the user to disk:)

### Enter MagicalRecord

Getting started with Magical Record is incredibly simple:

```
MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed(MyCoreDataStoreName)
```

This typically goes in your App Delegate. They also have tons of amazing categories on most Core Data classes for common Core Data operations as well as some well thought out infrastructure for handling multi-threading issues.

So now you want to establish a record in your database that there should only be one. Before you get started with that you must make sure that there is also only one object responsible for accessing this user attribute, or in the very least you make sure that only one object can create this user attribute.

For simplicities sake lets call this class the UserManager. The user manager will be responsible for managing all the operations we want to perform with our user. For now it just needs to make sure that when we access it, that there is always one in the database.

```
class UserManager {
    class var sharedManager : UserManager {
        struct Static {
            static let instance : UserManager = UserManager()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    func currentUser() -> CurrentUser {
        if let user = CurrentUser.MR_findFirst() as? CurrentUser {
            return user
        } else {
            let user = CurrentUser.MR_createEntity() as CurrentUser
            user.managedObjectContext!.MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait()
            return user
        }
    }
}
```

Now we have a singleton that will always guarantee that we have one user in the database. You also mentioned that you want to be able to update your user, a naive implementation could be added to our UserManager:

```
func updateUser(userUpdateHandler: ((user: CurrentUser) -> Void)) {
    MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock { (context) -> Void in
        let user = self.currentUser()
        userUpdateHandler(user: user)
        //as the app grows you could probably post a notification
        //here so any interested parties could update their info
        //if the user changes....
    }
}
```

Calling this from you View Controller is trivial:

```
    //the updateUser function isn't called
    //on the main thread so we need to capture
    //the values from the UI so we can safely use
    //them in the background
    let firstName = firstNameTextField.text
    let lastName = lastNameTextField.text
    let email = emailTextField.text
    let password = passwordTextField.text
    UserManager.sharedManager.updateUser { (user) -> Void in
        user.firstName = firstName
        user.lastName = lastName
        user.email = email
        user.password = password
        user.accountType = 0
    }
```

And voila, you have now implemented a pretty standard set of functions to deal with a user in your app.